# Error after update: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactMount'

Tags: reactjs, heroku

So I was trying to put my react-webpack app on Heroku when I started getting the error that ReactMount was not at React/lib/ReactMount. Then I tried a lot of different stuff and ended up trying to create a new project with the same react-webpack generater. And now I get the same mistake even when running on localhost meaning that it must be due to an update somewhere, right?

Does anyone know anything about this?

I have the following dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
"chai": "^3.2.0",
"copyfiles": "^1.0.0",
"css-loader": "^0.23.0",
"eslint": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"glob": "^7.0.0",
"isparta-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
"karma": "^1.0.0",
"karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
"karma-mocha": "^1.0.0",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
"karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
"minimist": "^1.2.0",
"mocha": "^3.0.0",
"null-loader": "^0.1.1",
"open": "0.0.5",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.0.0",
"react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
"rimraf": "^2.4.3",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.6",
"webpack": "^1.12.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0"


"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^2.0.0",
"firebase": "^3.5.2",
"input-moment": "^0.3.0",
"moment": "^2.15.2",
"normalize.css": "^4.0.0",
"react": "^15.0.0",
"react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
"react-datetimepicker-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
"react-dom": "^15.0.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.3"
```

Comment: What version of React are you using? They released a new version today, and it changed the internal API. Stuff inside `React/lib` was moved around; it's not part of the public API, and shouldn't be directly referenced. If you upgraded to React 15.4, that's probably the issue. If you're not explicitly referencing something internal, another package you're using might be.

Comment: I literally just got the same error, using React 15.3.1

Comment: I am using react 15.0.0 as shown in dependencies. I am sorry I am not very confident in all of this works but an update shouldn't effect the project with the way I have my dependencies now, right?

Comment: npm will resolve ^15.0.0 to the latest package up until just before version 16.0.0

Comment: Your dependency is for **at least** React 15.0.0; if you do an update, it'll get the latest. Do `npm list` to see what version is actually installed. And yes, it can very much affect things if React updates and some other module you're using hasn't changed to support the new React version. You can try `=15.3.2` for your React version and see if that helps.

Comment: Please add the specific error message to your question; it might help identify the module that's referencing `react/lib/ReactMount`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you and I were in the same boat. We were both using an old version of `react-hot-loader` update to version 3.x and do another npm install.

see - https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/417

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to simple change from react: ^15.0.0 to 15.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to update `react` in order to resolve this. In my case, I wasn't using hot loader. An upgrade to react resolved this. Currently on `15.4.0`

Answer (score -1):

Go to node_modules/react-hot-loader/index.js and use try catch instead of required

replace this code

```
prependText = [
'/* REACT HOT LOADER */',
'if (module.hot) {',
  '(function () {',
    'var ReactHotAPI = require(' + JSON.stringify(require.resolve('react-hot-api')) + '),',
        'RootInstanceProvider = require(' + JSON.stringify(require.resolve('./RootInstanceProvider')) + '),',
        'ReactMount = require("react/lib/ReactMount"),',
        'React = require("react");',

    'module.makeHot = module.hot.data ? module.hot.data.makeHot : ReactHotAPI(function () {',
      'return RootInstanceProvider.getRootInstances(ReactMount);',
    '}, React);',
  '})();',
'}',
'try {',
  '(function () {',
 ].join(' ');
```

to new code using try and catch to handle error

```
var reactMountImport;
   try {
 require('react-dom/lib/ReactMount');
     reactMountImport = 'ReactMount = require("react-dom/lib/ReactMount"),';
  } catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
  reactMountImport = 'ReactMount = require("react/lib/ReactMount"),';
  }

 prependText = [
'/* REACT HOT LOADER */',
'if (module.hot) {',
  '(function () {',
    'var ReactHotAPI = require(' + JSON.stringify(require.resolve('react-hot-api')) + '),',
        'RootInstanceProvider = require(' + JSON.stringify(require.resolve('./RootInstanceProvider')) + '),',
        reactMountImport,
        'React = require("react");',

    'module.makeHot = module.hot.data ? module.hot.data.makeHot : ReactHotAPI(function () {',
      'return RootInstanceProvider.getRootInstances(ReactMount);',
    '}, React);',
  '})();',
'}',
'try {',
  '(function () {',
].join(' ');
```

you can check changes here 
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/pull/430/commits/4ff08252bd8bf90dbc89fc6d032f557825ec0300#diff-168726dbe96b3ce427e7fedce31bb0bc

Comment: Editing node_modules manually is a bad idea, after an update they will break again.